# JQuery: How to reference element dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two-part development problem. In the first part, I set up several delegated event handlers:

```
$('#content').on('click','#button1',function1);
$('#content').on('click','#button2',function2);
```

Inside function1 and function2, among other processing, I set global variables to indicate which button was clicked:

```
function1(e) {
  ...
  var whichButtonClicked = $('#button1');
  ...
}

function2(e) {
  ...
  var whichButtonClicked = $('#button2');
  ...
}
```

Later, other code needs to remove the handler.

```
$('#content').off('click',whichButtonClicked,theFunctionRun);
```

However, the .off handler isn't working. It DOES work if I hardcode it to one of the buttons like this:

```
$('#content').off('click','#button1',theFunctionRun);
```

but then I lose the capability of being able to run it after either button functions.

How do I correct this statement:

```
$('#content').off('click',whichButtonClicked,theFunctionRun);
```

to make my code work?

I CAN run other commands on it, such as:

```
whichButtonClicked.trigger('click');
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nLorh2wm/20/

Comment: Have you tried `whichButtonClicked="#button1"`? That is, store the selector *string*, not a jquery object.

Comment: I think I just figured it out:

    $('#content').off('click',whichButtonClicked.id,theFunctionRun);

That is, I added the .id after the variable name. Is that logical?

Comment: That shouldn't work, because in your code the variable references a jquery object, and jquery objects don't have an `id` property. You'd need something like `$('#content').off('click', '#' +whichButtonClicked[0].id,theFunctionRun);` - note the concatenation of the '#' because the second parameter to `.off()` needs to be a selector, not a plain id, and the `[0]` to get a reference to the actual element from the jquery object.

Comment: That was my concern. It DID work, but I'm not sure that it's technically right. Sounds like you're saying it's not. Here's the fiddle where it's working:
https://jsfiddle.net/nLorh2wm/21/
Another possibility would be to do what you said about storing the string, and then when I need to run a function on it, like .trigger(), I would do something like this, I believe? $(whichButtonClicked).trigger...

Comment: @user3798040 I posted a working solution that involves slightly less code than that. And less is better :)

Comment: Ryan Little I like that better too, and I think it's what nnnnnn was saying. Thank you both.

Comment: I think `theButtonClicked.id` "works" in the fiddle because what that does is actually pass `undefined` as the second argument to `.off()`. As you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nLorh2wm/26/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just removing the `$(...)` around the element:

**Note:** The snippet doesn't seem to show alerts, but you can see it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/rplittle/nLorh2wm/23/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content').on('click', '#button1', function1);
  $('#content').on('click', '#button2', function2);
  $('#content').on('click', '#buttonAfter', followUpFunction);
});

var theButtonClicked;
var theFunctionRun;

function function1(e) {
  alert('in function1');
  theButtonClicked = '#button1';
  theFunctionRun = function1;
}

function function2(e) {
  alert('in function2');
  theButtonClicked = '#button2';
  theFunctionRun = function2;
}

function followUpFunction(e) {
  $('#content').off('click', theButtonClicked, theFunctionRun);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <button id="button1">
    Button 1
  </button>

  <button id="button2">
    Button 2
  </button>

  <button id="buttonAfter">
    Turn Off Handler for Button 1
  </button>
</div>
```